Meaning of 遊歷月餘? Does it mean a long and/or short trip?
I am reading this sentence: 他有多次日本自駕旅遊的經驗、去年也去了東歐四國遊歷月餘
What does 遊歷月餘 mean? Is it chengyu? Thanks.

"月餘" - "餘" means "surplus" or "in excess", so 月餘 means the length of his trip is more than one month.
